# Truffle test: "Cannot read property 'gasUsed' of null" error. Truffle migrate works fine

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-test

Whenever I try and do `truffle test` I get the error

```
Cannot read property 'gasUsed' of null
```

But `truffle migrate --reset` works fine

More confusingly, to rule out something in one of my tests that is causing the problem, I have deleted everything from the tests folder. So- to my understanding- if there is nothing in the tests folder, `truffle test` should do the exact same thing as `truffle migrate`?! Is there some separate configuration the tests are referring to that could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered what is causing the problem- the problem occurs when I specify a networkId on ganache of 69420. If I do not specify an ID, or even a network ID that is different by 1, it works.

It is NOT that truffle test cannot find the network- first, there is a different error message for that, and second, I have set truffle-config to search for networkID of "*".

Did someone hard code this network ID into truffle as being reserved or something!?

I feel like it could also be an easter egg..